# What is service_port used for in Ambassador

Tags: port, envoyproxy

I was under the impression that service_port was used to dictate which port envoy listens on its public ip.  That doesn't seem to be the case since as a non-root user, the ingress controller is listening on 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so maybe I think I misunderstood how Ambassador works.  Looks like it spins up a load balancer in the cloud that points to it.  It's the load balancer that's listening on 80/443, and the envoy proxy that listening on 8080/8443.